# POST data not received on server side

Tags: php, apache, post, http-post

I use Postman (the Chrome app) to send POST data to a URL but the POST data are never received by the PHP file, no matter how I change the content-type before sending. Is there a server setting on Apache that stops post data from external sources?

This is the URL:
http://friendesque.com/arranged/handler.php

And this is the content of the handler.php file:

```
<?php
     echo("Inside file");

     echo("JSON:");
     $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
     echo($json);

     echo("POST:");
     print_r($_POST);

     echo("GET:");
     print_r($_GET);
?>
```

Comment: Works fine: http://screencast.com/t/i6j24EnN3h

Comment: That's really wierd! Maybe it was a caching problem.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I'm gonna remove the question.

Answer (score 5):

In order for data to be available in **$_POST** array, the following conditions should be met:

1. Request must be sent with **POST** HTTP method
2. Content-Type header must be set to **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**
3. Request payload (body) must be in the form of **URL-encoded** parameters, e.g.

   ```
   param1=a&param2=b
   ```

I sent to your URL a request that meets those 3 conditions and got my data available in **$_POST** array.

Answer (score 0):

Use file name like /index.php . It will work !!